# Programatically Unchecking boxes based on selection

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two (or more words) that I want the checkbox states to be "checked" or "unchecked"

When the array loops a second time, it undoes the selection from the first index in the array.

```
    String[] Others = { "Conference", "Calendar" };
    filterSelection(Others);




    private void filterSelection(String location)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxArray.Length; i++)
        {
            checkBox = checkBoxArray[i];
            if (checkBox.Text.Contains(location))
            {
                checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
            }
            else
            {
                checkBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            }
            checkBoxArray[i] = checkBox;
        }
    }

    private void filterSelection(String[] location)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<location.Length; i++)
        {
            filterSelection(location[i]);
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway I can turn on and off the checkboxes based on the words in an array? (if you have a better idea, please provide a reason).

Comment: Note that `checkBoxArray[i] = checkBox;` is useless.  `CheckBox` is a reference type, changes made to `checkBox` affect the same object accessed through `checkBoxArray[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set all the checkboxes to unchecked as an independent step, and then when checking words, set matches to checked and skip those that aren't matches.

Or, reverse the loops and check all the strings at the same time.

```
private void filterSelection(String[] locations)
{
    foreach (var checkBox in checkBoxArray)
    {
        var willCheck = CheckState.Unchecked;
        foreach (string location in locations)
        {
            if (checkBox.Text.Contains(location))
            {
                willCheck = CheckState.Checked;
                break;
            }
        }
        checkBox.State = willCheck;
    }
}
```

In this case, the easiest way to avoid code duplication is to make the single-string version a case of the multi-string version.  And not call the single-string version from the multi-string one.  You could write:

```
private void filterSelection(String location)
{
    filterSelection(new [] { location });
}
```

But it's easier to just add the `params` keyword to the array version.

```
private void filterSelection(params String[] location)
```

Now you can still explicitly pass a string array.  But you can also pass one or more strings directly as arguments, and the compiler will create the array.  So both of these work:

```
String[] Others = { "Conference", "Calendar" };
filterSelection(Others);
```

or

```
filterSelection("Conference", "Calendar");
```